# How do I can redirect login, logout, register using rest_auth package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-packages

I'm using Django rest_auth package in my project. by default when I using login, logout and register It showing me a key I want to redirect users in my home URL but I can't. I have LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL but still it shows me the key and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL doesn't works. what should I do?????

Comment: Sorry I don't have experience with reast auth but did you try the demo project? https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demo.html - at the bottom of the demo settings there is a login and logout URL: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/demo/demo/settings.py

Comment: IMPORTANT: it appears reast_auth is not supported any more, you should swiitch to https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth instead!